# How do I change a document reference in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I volunteer for an organization and have been tasked with updating the website. I inherited the website and am performing edits in Dreamweaver 2017 CC. The homepage has a series of dropdown menus. One of the links within the dropdown causes a file download (.docx). I found the script and the associated file. I need to replace this file with a new version so I uploaded the new file to my _docs folder and changed the reference in the script. However, when I sync the local and remote server, the change isn't reflected. I am new at this so I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like a permission or cache problem

Comment: Be sure to completely clear your browser cache when uploading a new JS document to your server in order to force your browser to pull down the updated script. Ideally, you would want to use versioning for this so that you don't have to keep clearing your cache manually.

Comment: I cleared everything out and it still tries to download the old file. I have tried multiple computers and multiple browsers. Thank you for your help thought. I do appreciate it.